# derivative of DiracDelta

Tags: distributions, calculus-and-analysis

For the derivative of Dirac-Delta distributions one can show by using partial derivative that $\delta'(-x)=-\delta'(x)$. Thus, I wonder why Mathematica returns

```
In[1]= Integrate[foo[r] D[DiracDelta[ a - r], r], 
                  {r, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

Out[1]= ConditionalExpression[-foo'[a], a \[Element] Reals]
```

The output should be `foo'[a]` (see e.g. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Integration by parts says the given result is correct, or at least consistent with `Integrate[foo[r]*DiracDelta[a - r],  {r, -Infinity, Infinity}] `

Comment: Check the link concerning this integral, the order (a-x) is important

Comment: I'd say equation (10) covers the issue.

Comment: Check eq. 20, there is the correct result

Comment: My eyes might be playing tricks, but it looks like (19) and (20) conflict with one another, in a way that would be indicative of a typo.

Comment: in (19) there's $x-a$; in (20) there's $a-x$, hence the difference in signs in the respective right sides.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau No, I think everything is fine because $\delta'$ is an odd "function" - so in other words, the question is based on a misunderstanding. I saw that corey just remarked the same thing.

Comment: @Jens since my input is equal to eq.20 I don't understand Mathematica's output

Comment: Pen&paper integration - Eq. (19) and (20) are correct. It looks like MMA indeed doesn't understand the difference between `D[DiracDelta[a - x], x]` and `D[DiracDelta[x - a], x]` - both derivatives evaluate to the same result, and the respective integrals in (19) and (20) also. Bug?

Comment: @corey979 I think the problem is that `D[DiracDelta[a - r], r]` is not the same as `DiracDelta'[a - r]`, by the Chain Rule, so the input is not equivalent to eq. (20).  Note also the order of the terms in the argument of the **output** of `D[DiracDelta[x - a], x]`: the minus sign come from reversing the terms in `x - a` and the oddness of `DiracDelta'[]`.

Comment: Yup, @MichaelE2 hit the jackpot: `Integrate[f[r] DiracDelta'[a - r], {r, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` = $f'(a)$, and `Integrate[f[r] DiracDelta'[r - a], {r, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` = $-f'(a)$. There's a difference in using `D` and `'` for derivatives, but when one thinks about it _mathematically_ it makes lots of sense. So, no bug.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree, and maybe the following will give an alternative explanation: take the delta function as the limit of a Gaussian, then check `Simplify[D[Exp[-(a-x)^2/\[Epsilon]^2],x]==D[Exp[-(x-a)^2/\[Epsilon]^2],x]]` which yields `True`. This must remain so in the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ which is the delta function limit (without some factors). I've already voted to close.