# Fourier transform inconsistency

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis, singularity

**Bug introduced in 5 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.0**

---

On Mathematica 11.0.0 the Fourier transform of $x\theta(x)$ gives the [expected result:](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformRampFunction.html)

```
In: FourierTransform[x*UnitStep[x], x, t]
Out: -(1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*t^2)) - I*Sqrt[Pi/2]*Derivative[1][DiracDelta][t]
```

But the Fourier transform of $(x-a)\theta(x)$ misses the derivative of a delta function, and does not reduce to the previous answer when $a\rightarrow 0$:

```
In: FourierTransform[(x - a)*UnitStep[x], x, t]
Out: -(1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*t^2)) - (I*a)/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*t) - a*Sqrt[Pi/2]*DiracDelta[t]
```

Comment: [Related?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125907/derivative-of-diracdelta)

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to take the limit as `a` goes to zero here? You have to be pretty careful about that stuff in integration and distribution theory. In particular, one integrand is continuous and the other is is discontinuous at 0, and this might make a difference. It would probably be worth integrating your expressions against some test function and then taking the limit *after* and seeing if they're the same. I tried integrating `t^2 Exp[-(t - 1)^2]`, and upon the taking the limit as `a -> 0` *after* the integration, I got the same results.

Comment: @march -- the difference between the first and second integrands is $a\theta(x)$, which is a smooth function of $a$, without any discontinuity at $a=0$, so taking the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ of the integral over $x$ should be fine.

Comment: @march There is clearly an inconsistency if you expect the Fourier transform to be invertible (a fundamental property): `InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[(x-a) Sign[x],x,t],t,x]` doesn't produce the original function back again. So I think it has to be called a bug.

Comment: Distribution over `+` should clearly be valid in this case e.g. `(FourierTransform[x*UnitStep[x], x, t] - 
    FourierTransform[a*UnitStep[x], x, t]) - 
  FourierTransform[(x - a)*UnitStep[x], x, t] // FullSimplify` should be zero, and it is not.  This is a bug

Comment: FWIW, the bug persists even if you replace `UnitStep[]` with `HeavisideTheta[]`, even if the latter function is supposedly the function intended for use with the built-in integral transforms.

Comment: Bug still present in 11.1.0

Answer (score 6):

I've reported the issue to Wolfram and received this response:

> Thank you for taking the time to send in this report. It does appear
>   that the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of a
>   particular function is not behaving properly. In particular it is not
>   giving the original function back, as it should. I will forward an
>   incident report to our developers regarding this issue.

So this is a bug. The case number is `CASE:3710457`.

Comment: I decided to put the bug report case number in the answer instead of a comment, because this will make it easier to find in the future, in case I get additional feedback...

Comment: thank you, Jens, nice to catch up with you here!